# Dividir gráfico en dos o esconder los labels que no necesito

Tags: r

Código Barchart horizontal

```
p3 <-ggplot(PROMEDIOAT,                                     
     aes(x= reorder(NOMBRE_SERVICIO,-TIEMPO),TIEMPO))+
     geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#99FF33") +
     coord_flip() +
     ggtitle("Tiempo promedio Servicio")+
     geom_text(aes (label = round((TIEMPO),2) ), nudge_y = 0.1, color = "Black")+
     ylab("Tiempo (min)")+xlab("")+
     theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "gray"))
p3

p4 <- p3 + scale_y_discrete(breaks = PROMEDIOAT$NOMBRE_SERVICIO[1:10]) + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 10))
p4
```

Estoy realizando un diagrama de pareto pero tengo muchos labels y no los puedo visualizar en la gráfica, por lo que necesito dividir esta gráfica en dos o esconder algunos labels, este es el código del diagrama de pareto, Agradezco su ayuda.

```
EstadosUnidos <- BDTAQR %>%
  filter(BDTAQR$NOMBRE_SUBSEDE %in% c("EstadosUnidos"))


# # Sumar los valores únicos de por turno

UNICOS <- aggregate(ID_GESTION_ATENCION ~ NOMBRE_SERVICIO, BDTAQR, function(x) length(unique(x)))

## PARETO_TIPO_DE-SERVICIO

ggplot(UNICOS, aes(x = reorder(NOMBRE_SERVICIO, -ID_GESTION_ATENCION), y = ID_GESTION_ATENCION)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1)) + 
  stat_pareto(point.color = "blue",   
              point.size = 2,        
              line.color = "black",  
              #size.line = 1,        
              bars.fill = "#66CCFF")+
  ggtitle("Pareto Tipo Servicio")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  ylab("Cantidad")+xlab("")+
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "gray"))
```

Answer (score 1):

No hay muchas alternativas (1) ampliar el gráfico lo más que se pueda (2) achicar la letra de las etiquetas o (3) dividir el gráfico en más de uno. Voy a optar por este último punto. Por lo que pude probar, no funciona bien el facetado de `ggplot` con el `stat_pareto` (lástima por que haría más sencilla la solución), pero otra manera sería:

- Dividir los datos en grupos
- Hacer tantos gráficos como grupos tengamos
- Usar `gridExtra` para "acomodar" los plots

Veamos como sería. En primer lugar, armamos un ejemplo similar al tuyo:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("ggQC")

# Generamos un ejemplo similar
set.seed(2019)
rndString <- function(n = 5000) {
  a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), FALSE))
  paste0(a, sprintf("%04d", sample(9999, n, TRUE)), sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE))
}

BDTAQR = data.frame(ID_GESTION_ATENCION=1:5000, NOMBRE_SERVICIO=sample(rndString(100), 5000, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
UNICOS <- aggregate(ID_GESTION_ATENCION ~ NOMBRE_SERVICIO, BDTAQR, function(x) length(unique(x)))

UNICOS <- UNICOS[order(-UNICOS$ID_GESTION_ATENCION), ]
UNICOS$NOMBRE_SERVICIO <- factor(UNICOS$NOMBRE_SERVICIO, levels=UNICOS$NOMBRE_SERVICIO, ordered = TRUE)

# Graficamos todos los casos
ggplot(UNICOS, aes(x = NOMBRE_SERVICIO, y = ID_GESTION_ATENCION)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1)) + 
  stat_pareto(point.color = "blue",   
              point.size = 2,        
              line.color = "black",  
              #size.line = 1,        
              bars.fill = "#66CCFF")+
  ggtitle("Pareto Tipo Servicio")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  ylab("Cantidad")+xlab("")+
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "gray"))
```

El resultado final sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea entonces sería dividir este gráfico en dos y que cada uno hagan "zoom" sobre un parte de los valores:

```
# creamos el gráfico base
ggplot(UNICOS , aes(x = NOMBRE_SERVICIO, y = ID_GESTION_ATENCION)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1)) + 
  stat_pareto(point.color = "blue",   
              point.size = 2,        
              line.color = "black",  
              bars.fill = "#66CCFF")+
  ggtitle("Pareto Tipo Servicio")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  ylab("Cantidad") +
  xlab("") +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "gray")) -> p

# Armamos las dos graficas
p1 <- p + scale_x_discrete(breaks = UNICOS$NOMBRE_SERVICIO[1:50]) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 50))
p2 <- p + scale_x_discrete(breaks = UNICOS$NOMBRE_SERVICIO[51:100]) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(51, 100))
# Las organizamos una arriba de la otra
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 1)
```

Y ahora, la gráfica dividida en dos, tienes que ver si en definitiva te sigue siendo útil verlo así, pero al menos logramos hacer más legibles la etiquetas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con `coord_cartesian()` ajustamos el área que vamos a visualizar del gráfico, hacer esto es mejor que dividir los datos y hacer dos gráficos independientes, ya que de esta forma mantenemos la misma escala en los dos gráficos. Normalmente con `coord_cartesian()` alcanza para ajustar el gráfico, pero en este caso pareciera que `stat_pareto()` no es del todo consistente con `ggplopt`, así que si bien se hace el zoom, se siguen mostrando etiquetas más allá de los ejes, por lo que hay que ajustar esto también mediante `scale_x_discrete()` y dejar sola las etiquetas que queremos ver.

Comment: Patricio mil gracias por tu ayuda, me sirve muchísimo la solución.  De pronto sabes como podría esconder datos y solo mostrar los que tengan las barras mas grandes?

Comment: El tema es si solo quieres quitar las etiquetas o además esas barras. En el primer caso, entiendo que puedes establecer que etiquetas mostrar mediante el parámetro `breaks` de `scale_x_discrete()`. Si quieres quitar las barras directamente, deberías eliminar esos casos del `data.frame` original.

Comment: Perfecto!!, muchas gracias

Comment: Hola como estas, agradezco tu ayuda con esta consulta ahora estoy intentando dividir un gráfico horizontal en varias partes, pero al intentarlo me cambia el sentido de la gráfica, este es el código. Lo dejo en la parte superior

Comment: Hola @LinaHernandez, no modifiques la pregunta original, eso invalida cualquier respuesta que tuviera, te sugiero (entiendo que es tedioso) que armes una nueva pregunta, y además, algo muy importante, llegarás a una audiencia más amplia.